# How to match a regex pattern group for fixed no of time?

Tags: regex

I wrote a regex which basically matches the group, however I want to limit its searching such that it doesn't look for match till end and stop if n groups are found.

My log --

```
[Mon Feb 27 15:40:12.341031 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2420:tid 332] [AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...]
```

My pattern-

```
([^\[\]]+)
```

THe above pattersn is able to match all however I just want to group only first 2 i.e ***[Mon Feb 27 15:40:12.341031 2017] [auth_digest:notice]***

Some thing like-

```
([^\[\]]+){2}
```

Individual character or words work using eg (abc){2} but how about group ?
Is it possible ?

Comment: Try `^\[([^\]\[]*)\]\s*\[([^\]\[]*)\]` and grab Group 1 and 2 values/

Comment: [`^\s*(\[[^]]*)]\s*\[([^]]*)]`](https://regex101.com/r/9v4xym/1)

Comment: My requirement is something using one pattern and it should stop with 2 and not match 3 /4.


```
Match1 = [Mon Feb 27 15:40:12.341031 2017]
Match 2 = [auth_digest:notice]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern `([^\[\]]+)` uses a negated character class which matches not `[` and `]` and does not take the structure of the opening and closing brackets into account.

Repeating it with `{2}` repeats the group and will result in a match and a capturing group where the group contains the match of the last iteration.

If you want the 2 matches from the start of the string you could use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and use 2 capturing groups with a space between matching `(\[[^]]+\])` which will include the opening and closing square brackets.

```
^(\[[^]]+\]) (\[[^]]+\])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6EKmaJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try thiss. You just need to handle the one extra white space at the end.

```js
const str = "[Mon Feb 27 15:40:12.341031 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2420:tid 332] [AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...]";


const regex = /(?:\[.+?\] ){2}/;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: I think I am unable to phrase my question correctly, using above regex I am getting one single match however my requirement is _

    Match1 = [Mon Feb 27 15:40:12.341031 2017]

    Match 2 = [auth_digest:notice]